# boost::bind don't compile with member template function

Tags: c++

I just write an simple example to test boost::bind. I use it to instantiate a template member function, but it won't compile with g++ 4.6.0. I don't know what's the problem.
Here's the code:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

struct Functor
{
  void operator()()
  {

  }
};

struct DerivedFinishAction
{
  DerivedFinishAction()
  {}

  void Inc()
  {

  }

  template <typename T>
  void TmplFunc(T t)
  {
    (boost::bind(&DerivedFinishAction::BindFunc<T>, this , t))();
  }

  template <typename T>
  void BindFunc(T t)
  {
    t();
  }

  void Func()
  {
    Functor f;
    TmplFunc(f); // this is OK
    TmplFunc(boost::bind(&DerivedFinishAction::Inc, this)); // compile error
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  return 0;
}
```

And g++ gives the following errors:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:22:0,
                 from testBind.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp: In member function ‘void boost::_bi::list2<A1, A2>::operator()(boost::_bi::type<void>, F&, A&, int) [with F = boost::_mfi::mf1<void, DerivedFinishAction, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, DerivedFinishAction>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<DerivedFinishAction*> > > >, A = boost::_bi::list0, A1 = boost::_bi::value<DerivedFinishAction*>, A2 = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, DerivedFinishAction>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<DerivedFinishAction*> > >]’:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:20:59:   instantiated from ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::operator()() [with R = void, F = boost::_mfi::mf1<void, DerivedFinishAction, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, DerivedFinishAction>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<DerivedFinishAction*> > > >, L = boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<DerivedFinishAction*>, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, DerivedFinishAction>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<DerivedFinishAction*> > > >, boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type = void]’
testBind.cpp:24:5:   instantiated from ‘void DerivedFinishAction::TmplFunc(T) [with T = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf0<void, DerivedFinishAction>, boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<DerivedFinishAction*> > >]’
testBind.cpp:37:58:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:313:9: error: invalid use of void expression
```

Can anybody help explain this? Why the first instantiation is OK while the second one causes compile error?

Comment: @SethCarnegie, 15 minutes, just for that XD

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a (non-obvious) feature of `boost::bind` involved here.  http://www.boost.org/libs/bind/#nested_binds

If you write:

```
void func1(int len) {return len+1;};
int func2(std::string str) {return str.length();};

assert(
    boost::bind(func1, boost::bind(func2, _1) )("Hello")
    == 6 );
```

`boost::bind` assumes that what you meant is "run `func2` on `"Hello"`, then run `func1` on the result".  This allows more interesting partial function application.

In your program, you have an expression which amounts to:

```
boost::bind(&DerivedFinishAction::BindFunc<...>, 
            this, 
            boost::bind(&DerivedFinishAction::Inc, this))
```

So `boost::bind` tries to figure out how to run `DerivedFinishAction::Inc` on it arguments, so it can pass that result into `DerivedFinishAction::BindFunc<...>`.  But `DerivedFinishAction::Inc` returns void, which cannot be passed into `DerivedFinishAction::BindFunc<...>`.  Thus you get a compiler error:

```
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:313:9: error: invalid use of void expression
```

**Edit**: Per the documentation, you can use `protect` to achieve your desired behavior:

```
#include <boost/bind/protect.hpp>
...
TmplFunc(boost::protect(boost::bind(&DerivedFinishedAction::Inc, this))); // no longer an error
...
```

Comment: This feature of `boost::bind` also applies to `std::bind`.

Comment: The solution is great. Thanks @Managu